# Test to detect if a template type in C++/CLI is managed or unmanaged

Tags: c++-cli

I have some template code compiled with /clr, something like the following

```
template <typename T> void foo( )
{
}
```

and am wondering if it's possible to detect if the T is a managed type or an unmanaged one. So something like

```
template <typename T> void foo( )
{
     constexpr bool b = is_managed_type<T>;
}
```

If have tried all the std library type traits and those mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/compiler-support-for-type-traits-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019 but have not found anything that works in all cases. A particular instance of this problem is to tell if an enum is a managed enum or an unmanaged one. So is it possible to implement a type trait like this?

Added 9/23/19
I did make some progress on a is_managed_type trait. I have the following

```
int check( System::Object^ );

template <typename T, typename U = void> using converts_to_system_object_t = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));


template<typename T, typename = void> struct is_managed_type: std::false_type {};

template<typename T> struct is_managed_type<T, converts_to_system_object_t<T>> : std::true_type { };
```

The basic idea is to test if for given type can you call a function that takes os System::Object^. Note I did try things like std::is_base_of and std::is_convertible but they all had problems.
However this seem to return false for managed enums which is a bit bizzare to me

Comment: The description of `__is__enum` on that page is "Returns true if the type is a native enum".  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I did try __is_enum and it returns true for a managed enum and an unmanaged one, by unmanaged I mean 'enum class'. I must admit I'm not sure how things work for old style C++ enums as they use the keyword 'enum' as well.

Comment: So `__is__enum` gives no difference between `enum class` and `public enum class`?

Comment: That is correct __is_enum always returns true no matter how I declare an enum

Comment: At https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/enum-class-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019 I find the statement "If a standard C++ enum is defined (without class or struct), **compiling with /clr will cause the enumeration to be compiled as a managed enum**. The enumeration still has the semantics of an unmanaged enumeration. Note, the compiler injects an attribute, `Microsoft::VisualC::NativeEnumAttribute` to identify a programmer's intent for the enum to be a native enum. Other compilers will simply see the standard enum as a managed enum." You detect `/clr` with `__cplusplus_cli `

Comment: Ah very helpful I had not seen that thanks. I wish the designers had used something like "value enum" in /CLR code or something else to clearly indicate you intent to create a managed enum.

Comment: I did make a little progress on the is_managed_type trait but am still having issues

Comment: Well, when `enum class` was added to C++/CLI it was the clear indicator that the enum should be managed.  Then C++11 co-opted the syntax because of how well it balanced backward compatibility with terseness.  So now `public enum class` (or `private enum class`) is the incantation for a managed enum.  Telling the compiler you want a managed enum is not the problem.  The problem is that when `/clr` is in effect, the compiler is generating managed code for everything, not just "managed" types.